# Writing a TCP Server/Client in OCaml with Async

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

Beginner in OCaml here, and heard that it's pretty good at building networking applications. Decided to get my hands dirty with the Async library.

I'm trying to implement something like netcat, where a server and client can send messages to each other.

This is the function that starts the server:

```
let start_server p =
    let host_and_port =
        Tcp.Server.create
        ~on_handler_error:`Raise
        (Tcp.Where_to_listen.of_port p)
        (fun sock reader writer ->
            conn_handler sock reader writer)
in
ignore (host_and_port : (Socket.Address.Inet.t, int) Tcp.Server.t Deferred.t);
Deferred.never ()
```

This is the function that starts the client:

```
let start_client a p =
    Tcp.with_connection
    (Tcp.Where_to_connect.of_host_and_port { host = a; port = p})
    (fun sock reader writer ->
        conn_handler sock reader writer)
```

Both functions call the function `conn_handler`, which implements of message sending logic.

The client/server has to simultaneously be able to:

1. read message from `stdin` and send it.
2. receive messages and send back an "message recved".

Current implementation of `conn_handler`:

```
let rec conn_handler s r w =`
    let stdin = Lazy.force Reader.stdin in
    Reader.read_line stdin >>= function
    | `Eof -> return ()
    | `Ok x ->
        Writer.write_line w x;

    Reader.read_line r >>= function
    | `Eof  -> return ()
    | `Ok "exit" -> return ()
    | `Ok x -> 
        print_endline x;
        Writer.write_line w "Acknowledged";
        conn_handler s r w
```

There's an error in the sequencing of the logic which i'm not able to figure it out. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve both functionalities concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be easily seen if you will enable automatic indentation of your code, e.g., using ocp-indent. For example, your code,

```
let rec conn_handler s r w =
    let stdin = Lazy.force Reader.stdin in
    Reader.read_line stdin >>= function
    | `Eof -> return ()
    | `Ok x ->
        Writer.write_line w x;

    Reader.read_line r >>= function
    | `Eof  -> return ()
    | `Ok "exit" -> return ()
    | `Ok x -> 
        print_endline x;
        Writer.write_line w "Acknowledged";
        conn_handler s r w
```

will be indented as

```
let rec conn_handler s r w =
  let stdin = Lazy.force Reader.stdin in
  Reader.read_line stdin >>= function
  | `Eof -> return ()
  | `Ok x ->
    Writer.write_line w x;
    (* woops, it actually happens in this branch *)
    Reader.read_line r >>= function
    | `Eof  -> return ()
    | `Ok "exit" -> return ()
    | `Ok x ->
      print_endline x;
      Writer.write_line w "Acknowledged";
      conn_handler s r w
```

The problem is two-fold. First, you're trying to use the semicolon `;` to separate two match expressions, but since `;` has higher precedence it just binds the second match to the second branch of the first match. In other words, a semicolon doesn't act as a match terminator, it just sequences an expression to the left with an expression to the right.

```
 match x with
 | X -> ()
 | Y -> 
   do_something ();
   do_something_else ();
   match y with
   | Z -> ...
```

if you really want to do two matches one after another, you need to use parentheses (or `begin/end`) to delimit them, e.g.,

```
 begin match x with 
  | A -> ..
  | ...
  | Z -> ..
 end;
 begin match y with 
  | A -> ..
  | ...
  | Z -> ..
 end;
```

So what your connection handler is reading a line from the standard input, when it is ready it post a job to the writer queue and only after it is read and write is posted, the read from the channel `r` happens.

We couldn't really use a semicolon here to combine our two tasks, because both tasks are deferred, i.e., they have type `unit Deferred.t` not `unit`. So we have to use some of the combinators provided by the `Deferred` interface. We can use `both` which has type `'a t -> 'b t -> ('a * 'b) t` but since both of our tasks evaluate to the `unit` value there is probably no reason to build the `(),()` value. So we could use the `all_unit` combinator, that takes a list of tasks and evaluates to `unit Deferred.t` which will become determined as soon as all tasks are determined, e.g., the following implementation is a little bit closer to your intent,

```
let rec conn_handler s r w =
  let stdin = Lazy.force Reader.stdin in
  let task1 = Reader.read_line stdin >>= function
    | `Eof -> return ()
    | `Ok x ->
      Writer.write_line w x;
      return () in
  let task2 = Reader.read_line r >>= function
    | `Eof  -> return ()
    | `Ok "exit" -> return ()
    | `Ok x ->
      print_endline x;
      Writer.write_line w "Acknowledged";
      return () in
  Deferred.all_unit [
    task1;
    task2;
  ] >>= fun () ->
  conn_handler s r w
```

At each step, we read one line from stdin and, in parallel, read one line from the provided input and write the "Acknowledged" message. It will then wait until both tasks are finished and repeat. So we again created an unfortunate synchronization. So probably we designed our step incorrectly, as each individual task should have its own loop, instead of having one loop that runs two task in a sequence, e.g.,

```
 let conn_handler s r w =
  let stdin = Lazy.force Reader.stdin in
  let rec task1 () = Reader.read_line stdin >>= function
    | `Eof -> return ()
    | `Ok x ->
      Writer.write_line w x;
      task1 () in
  let rec task2 () = Reader.read_line r >>= function
    | `Eof  -> return ()
    | `Ok "exit" -> return ()
    | `Ok x ->
      print_endline x;
      Writer.write_line w "Acknowledged";
      task2 () in
  Deferred.any_unit [
    task1 ();
    task2 ();
  ]
```

Now, we are running two tasks independently and stop as soon as any of the two stops.

Although the example is demonstrative the task itself is much easier solved using the pipes mechanism in Async. Something like this,

```
let conn_handler s r w =
  let input = Reader.lines (Lazy.force Reader.stdin) in
  let src = Reader.pipe r
  and dst = Writer.pipe w in
  Deferred.any_unit [
    Pipe.transfer_id input dst;
    Pipe.transfer src dst ~f:(function
        | "exit" -> Pipe.close_read src; "Goodbye"
        | s ->
          print_endline ("Received: " ^ s);
          "Acknowledged")
  ]
```